# Looping over a list and a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.x

I think the title is correct. If not, I apologize.

I have `aList` defined as

```
[24, 19, 18, 15, 15, 23, 18, 15, 18, 15]
```

and `aDict` defined as

```
{'1': 18, '2': 76, '3': 0, '4': 13, '5': 4, '6': 30, '7': 25, '8': 21}
```

and a `masterDict` defined (initialized with 0s) as

```
{'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
```

How can I check whether each element in `aList` matches a value in `aDict`? If it does, increment the corresponding key in `masterDict` by 1?

The code i'm currently using is

```
for x in aList:
    for k, v in aDict.iteritems():
        if x == v:
            masterDict[k] = +1
```

However, this is returning a `masterDict` that looks like this

```
{'1': 1, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
```

`aList` contains three occurrences of the element `18` and it matches a value in `aDict`. I'm looking to increment the corresponding key in `masterDict` three times. However, it's only incrementing one time.

The output i'm looking to produce is

```
{'1': 3, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of typo in your code - should be `masterDict[k] += 1`
 instead of `masterDict[k] = +1`

after change output is: `{'1': 3, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use for `k` in `dct` and if the value that key produces matches item in `lst` then increase the `k` in `mst` by 1

```
mstr = {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
dct = {'1': 18, '2': 76, '3': 0, '4': 13, '5': 4, '6': 30, '7': 25, '8': 21}
lst = [24, 19, 18, 15, 15, 23, 18, 15, 18, 15]

for i in lst:
    for k in dct:
        if dct[k] == i:
            mstr[k] += 1

print(mstr)
# {'1': 3, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
```

Comment: @yodish yep I see now ha simple typo :)